# Format a SSD from Mac OS Extended to NTFS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, ntfs

I have a SSD formated in Mac OS Extended, and I want to format it to NTFS because I will use it on Windows.

To do it, I installed Paragon. I rebooted my MacBook. I checked if the driver was actived, and it was. So I went to Disk Utilty, but I have no choice to format to NTFS. Only Mac OS Extended is proposed.

I tried with Tuxera too. But same result, it didn't show the NTFS option.

Do you know any other way to format a SSD or a HDD from Mac OS Extended to NTFS ?

Comment: Why don't you format the disk from the Windows side?

Comment: The thing is I will use the ssd on a new pc, and install windows on it. So I don't have windows yet. But I managed to do it, I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

I respond to myself because I managed to do it. On my SSD I had an installation of OS X Yosemite, so I couldn't format it directly to NTFS.

So I first format the SSD to Mac OS Extended. And then I could choose the NTFS format option from Disk Utility.

Comment: Just formatted a pen drive to Mac OS Extended but NTFS format option was not listed in Disk Utility.